# HTML5 Canvas base64 encoded string to xml and MS Word

Tags: jquery, xml, vbscript, ms-word, base64

I am working on a proof of concept involving a Panasonic Toughpad. The goal to use the internal webcam to document defects in the field, categorize them and save the data to xml.
Furthermore, the taken pictures need to be edited with a stylus to highlight areas of interest. These information will then be read from xml into a MS Word document, including the images.
The Toughpad is running Windows 7 in spite of Windows 8. Atm I am only allowed to play with ASP or MS InfoPath. ( Don't ask me why ....)

I am using HTML5 and jquery ( ISS server ) to access the webcam, save the snapshot into a canvas and use some additional functions to draw on the canvas image. The original image is 640x380 pixels.

I then use canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg") to get the encoded stream. This will be passed by ajax to a classic asp script ( vbscript) which in turn will add/edit/delete the data to xml.

For some reason, I cannot put the base64 string into xml as binary.

The node is classified as bin.base64:

```
nodeB64.DataType = "bin.base64" ' stores binary as base64 string
nodeB64.Text = Mid(base64String2, InStr(base64String2, ",") + 1) ' append data text (all data after the comma, so we will have the pure encoded data)
```

The error:

```
msxml3.dll error "80004005'
Error Parsing "/9k...." as bin.base64 datatype
```

So for now I stored the base64 as String Node.

In all HTML webpages I can display the image flawlessly:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg....."/>
```

The images need to be embedded into MS Word. MS Word does not understand base64 image strings. As it will not display a picture.

So I tried to create a binary file saved to disk or memory inorder to use the mem function or classic image insert function for MS Word using vbscribt.

Example:

```
Set tmpDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
Set nodeB64 = tmpDoc.CreateElement("b64")
nodeB64.DataType = "bin.base64" 
nodeB64.Text = {my_base_64_encoded_string}

Dim oStream
Set oStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Type=1
oStream.Open
oStream.Write nodeB64.NodeTypedValue
oStream.SaveToFile "C:\test10.jpg" , 2
oStream.Close()
```

This will not work with the usual taken images from the webcam.

Using the following base64 encoded gif string as a test ( very small gif icon ):

```
R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM///// wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==
```

All works. Inserting into the xml file as well as saving it as a binary image file.

The following examples either work not at full expectations or not at all

[Not creating errors, but saved jpeg file is shown incomplete](http://pastebin.com/nXRHUKef)

[This normal webcam picture with drawings does trigger all mentioned errors](http://pastebin.com/A4XzGA5C)

The only difference is the length of base64 characters which can be ridiculously long.

Am I pushing the envelop too far ? Or are their techniques I have not found googling it ?

Comment: Could it be a char/escape sequence? Have you tried examining the base64 data around the point your [JPEG image](http://pastebin.com/nXRHUKef) becomes truncated?

Comment: Well I will have a look at that. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Many Thanks Bond. Isse solved. The problem was the urlencoding so I can post to the handler asp page. All is working fine now.

Comment: Good to hear, @MrSlacky!